# Access gallery images from pre-installed gallery in Android TV

Tags: android, android-tv

I am developing android TV application in which i want to access all images which are pre-installed in gallery of Android TV.

I want to load all these images in my application. For that i have dig a google and tried to find solution but i couldn't find anything.

**Edit :**

As per `@AndiGeeky` suggested to use `ContentProvider`. So my question is that does it has the same process for fetching or loading images from gallery using `URI` as we do normally for mobile devices?

Have anyone done before ? Advanced help would be appreciated !

Comment: Have you tried `ContentProvider`?

Comment: Can we access by it? Does it have the same scenario of accessing the gallery images as we do for normal phone gallery?

Comment: @ Piyush Gupta: Yes. I have developed on TV app in which i am getting path of images in TV using content provider!

Comment: @AndiGeeky Can you please share some snippet for it?

Comment: @ Piyush Gupta: Sure I will share later!

Comment: @AndiGeeky If you don't mind can you please share now because its my urgent requirement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136238/discussion-between-andigeeky-and-piyush-gupta).

Answer (score 1):

Please find below method to get image list from `ContentResolver`:

```
public ArrayList<String> getImageList() {
        ArrayList<String> list_image = new ArrayList<>();
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED);
        if (cursor.moveToLast()) {
            do {
                list_image.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)));
            } while (cursor.moveToPrevious());
            cursor.close();
        }
        return list_image;
    }
```

Comment: Ok so will this return all images from TV gallery ?

Comment: @Piyush Gupta: It will give you an uri(path) of image file. You can get image using this path!